# Transformers and switching converters

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, flyback, induction

I have been reading about the concept of  flyback transformers and converters, which has led to various misunderstandings concerning the basic operation of a transformer.
Firstly, dc current don't induce voltage in the secondary windings of any transformer. But in a flyback converter, I read that when the switch is ON, current will build up in the primary winding, and a diode that was added in the secondary winding will prevent current flowing in the secondary winding, until the switch is open or OFF.
Same with a RCC converter.When the transistor turns ON, current will be induced in the auxillary winding.How does this happen?
So can a dc or a short constant current induce voltage in another winding of a transformer?

Comment: Picture either a simple flyback or forward converter, during the period that the "pulse is HIGH", the switching transistor is turned ON, and current will flow in the primary winding.
In the case of flyback converter; an opposite polarity voltage will be induced in the secondary winding, which reverses bias the diode.
In the case of a forward converter; a same polarity voltage will be induced simultaneously in the secondary winding.
My main difficulty is, why are these voltages induced in the secondary winding when the input pulse is still ON(no change in current)?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Have you read any books, articles or the Wikipedia page about flyback converters?

Comment: When the primary switch is ON, it's not DC flowing in the primary. If you put a current measurement device in series with the winding, you will not see DC current. You will see (in most cases) a smooth ramp of current. *Changing* current. The primary winding is not a simple resistive short-circuit, there's inductance.

Answer (score 1):

> *Firstly, dc current don't induce voltage in the secondary windings of
>   any transformer.*

Correct, a steady DC current doesn't induce secondary voltage. However, if the DC current is ramping up or ramping down in value it does.

> *But in a flyback converter, I read that when the switch is ON, current
>   will build up in the primary winding*

Correct, and that ramping current induces a voltage. However, because of the polarity of the diode in the secondary circuit, that voltage can do no work i.e. it can't force a current into the load. So, current ramps up in the primary accumulating magnetic energy along the way and no energy transfers to the output load.

> *prevent current flowing in the secondary winding, until the switch is
>   open or OFF*

Correct, when the switch turns off or goes open circuit, the magnetic energy forces current to flow into either the primary or the secondary. Given that the primary is now an open circuit, it forces current to flow into the diode and deliver the stored energy to the load. It can do this because the current is ramping down and that produces a reversal in voltage on the secondary that then forward biases the diode.

> *When the transistor turns ON, current will be induced in the auxillary
>   winding.*

Current is not induced in magnetic elements; voltage is induced and, if there is a path for current to flow then current will flow.

> *So can a dc or a short constant current induce voltage in another
>   winding of a transformer?*

In the long term DC is static and doesn't have the credentials to induce voltage: -

$$\text{induced voltage} = \text{inductance}\cdot \dfrac{\text{change in current}}{\text{change in time}} \Longrightarrow V = L\cdot\dfrac{di}{dt}$$

> *My main difficulty is, why are these voltages induced in the secondary
>   winding when the input pulse is still ON(no change in current)?*

When the primary is attached to the DC voltage source (V), the current rises linearly at a rate of V/L amps per second where L is the inductance of the primary winding. It's basically a re-arrangement of the formula I gave above. That linear rising current induces a voltage on the secondary terminals.

Comment: Thank you so much for using your time and effort in the explanation. So a short pulse will be induced in the secondary winding in the moment of time the primary current is still rising?.

Comment: A constant secondary voltage will be induced with a linear rising primary current. That will remain provided the primary current remains linearly rising.